# listing files using C#, file with % wont open

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-listing

I am listing pdf files using C#, but some files wont open because they have percentage(`%`) signs on their filenames, the user still wants the `%` to be shown on the filename, but I can't get it to work.

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo("mydirectory/News Files");
FileSystemInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.pdf");

var orderedFiles = files.OrderByDescending(f => f.Name);
foreach (FileSystemInfo file in orderedFiles)
{
    var link = new HyperLink { ID = file.FullName };
    link.NavigateUrl ="/News Files/"+ file.Name;
    link.Text = Regex.Split(file.Name, ".pdf")[0];
    link.CssClass = "linkpdf";
    newsListContainer.Controls.Add(link);
}
```

But with this code file with the name like `my20%sign.pdf` will not open in the browser.

Comment: Are you saying that the filenames *actually* have a `%` in them? Or they just display like that? Why won't the files open?

Comment: yeah the filename has a % on them

Answer (score 2):

You could try `Uri.EscapeUriString`.

Also, you shouldn't construct urls/filenames using string concatenation with `/`.  You should usually use a Uri/filename parsing library, such as the `Uri` class

Answer (score 1):

That's not surprising. The %20 is interpreted by the browser as a "white space", as it is the url encoded equivalent value. So if your file is named "My%20File.pdf", the browser will decode the url and actually look for "My File.pdf".

For further reference, check this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: You're right, tho the filename is `my20%sign`, not `my%20sign`.  Took me a second to figure that out, too :)

Comment: yeah the file is my20%sign so i don't know why it is not display.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `%20` with `" ". filename.replace("%20"," ");`